# Python: Freeze arguments into a class __init__ function

Tags: python

Suppose I have a class that looks like this:

```
  class MyClass(object):
        def __init__(self, some_arg, param=None):
            self.some_arg = some_arg
            self.param = param
```

In most instances I initialize my class like this:

```
obj = MyClass(1, param='some_string')
```

But I'll occasionally have a code path which sets the `param` keyword argument based on some logic, while holding the `some_arg` positional argument at a constant value. This code would look something like:

```
if some_condition:
   obj = MyClass(1, param='some_string')
elif some_other_condition:
   obj = MyClass(1, param='some_other_string')
else:
   obj = MyClass(1, param='some_third_string')
```

My question is: Can I avoid having to repeat myself for the `MyClass(1` portion of my object instantiation? I would like to, for the duration of the code path, freeze the value of the positional `some_arg` as `1`, and simply pass the keyword argument `param` at instantiation time.

Ideally the code would look something like this:

```
MyClass = magic_function_to_freeze_some_arg(MyClass, some_arg=1)

if some_condition:
   obj = MyClass(param='some_string')
elif some_other_condition:
   obj = MyClass(param='some_other_string')
else:
   obj = MyClass(param='some_third_string')

print(obj.some_arg) # Always 1 regardless of which if condition is hit
```

Any ideas for what a clean implementation of `magic_function_to_freeze_some_arg` would look like? Is there a means to do this via Python standard library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)!

```
from functools import partial

MyClass_new = partial(MyClass, some_arg=1)
```

alternatively (as mgilson mentions in the comments) you can build your own anonymous constructor method

```
MyClass_new = lambda *args,**kwargs: MyClass(*args, some_arg=1, **kwargs)
```

Comment: And there's always `lambda` as well (if you don't want the extra import) ... :-)

Comment: Thanks! Tried both of these approaches and they work. Still, I wonder if it's possible to do this without binding to a new name in the local namespace? Would be the nice to continue to use `MyClass` for the code path instead of `MyClass_new`

Comment: @Adam actually `MyClass = partial(MyClass, some_arg=1)` throws an `UnboundLocalError` in 3.4 ostensibly because `MyClass` is no longer bound by the time `partial` is called.

Comment: @talwai huh, weird. I thought `partial` would work as a closure, binding the function when called before assigning it to the same old variable name. Regardless I wouldn't do that anyway :)

Comment: Strange: `print(inspect.getfullargspec(functools.partial(MyClass, 1)).args)` prints `['some_arg', 'param']`. Why? Seems like `partial` removes the `self` instead of `some_arg`.

Comment: @yankee yeah that makes sense. Since `self` is the first argument in the `__init__` method, `partial` will replace it if given positional arguments. Using keyword arguments (as in the answer and comments above) corrects that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of repeating `MyClass`, store the argument in a variable and apply that:

```
if some_condition:
   param = 'some_string'
elif some_other_condition:
   param = 'some_other_string'
else:
   param = 'some_third_string'

obj = MyClass(1, param=param)
```

You could create a [`functools.partial()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) or a `lambda` function but for this case that's overkill.

Comment: yup that is definitely cleaner code. But my example was a bit over-simplified and what I really wanted to do was raise an `Exception` with some frozen arguments, meaning that I would need the object instantiated right away rather than outside the `if` block.